# Reducing number of Line Breaks/chr(10) in a Cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, newline

I have an excel sheet that has cells with variable amounts of line breaks and I want to reduce it so that there is only one line break between each new line.

For example

```
HELLO




WORLD



GOODBYE
```

will be modified to:

```
HELLO 

WORLD

GOODBYE
```

I've been banging my head over this for hours and have come up with a few ways but none are very efficient or produce the best results.

This is made especially difficult because I'm working with a dataset that has spaces preceeding the Line Breaks.

[image]

And so a regular parse doesn't work as well.

I've tried to replace all the instances of `chr(10)` in the cell with `~` to make it easier to work with, however i'm still not getting it to an exact amount. I'm wondering if there are better ways.

here is what I have so far:

```
 myString = Replace(myString, Chr(10), "~")

    Do While InStr(myString, "~~") > 0
        str1 = Split(myString, "~")
        For k = 0 To UBound(str1)
        myString = Replace(myString, "~~", "~")
        Next k
    Loop

    Do While InStr(myString, "   ~") > 0
        str1 = Split(myString, "~")
        For k = 0 To UBound(str1)
        myString = Replace(myString, "  ~", "")
        Next k
    Loop

myString = Replace(myString, "   ~", " ~")
myString = Replace(myString, " ~", "~")
myString = Replace(myString, "~", Chr(10))

Cells(2, 2).Value = myString
```

So i'm using a few do while loops to catch instances of different types of line breaks (or in this case, tildes) but I don't think this is the best way to tackle this.

I was thinking of ways to loop through the characters in the cell, and if there is an instance where there is more than one chr(10), replace it with `""`.

So the psuedocode would look like:

```
for i to len(mystring)
    if mystring(i) = chr(10) AND myString(i+1) = chr(10) Then
       myString(i + 1) = ""
```

but unfortunately I don't think this is possible through vba.

If anyone is kind enough to help me adjust my current code or assist me with the aforementioned psuedocode, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is it always a single word or can there be multiples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ","|"),"|"&CHAR(10)," "),CHAR(10)," "))," ",CHAR(10)),"|"," ")
```

This changes all the spaces to `|` and then the `Char(10)` to spaces.  The trim removes the extra spaces.  The we reverse, space to `Char(10)` and `|` to spaces.

[image]

---

VBA:

```
Function manytoone(str As String)
    str = Replace(Application.Trim(str), " ", "|")
    str = Replace(str, "|" & Chr(10), " ")
    str = Replace(str, Chr(10), " ")
    str = Application.Trim(str)
    str = Replace(str, " ", Chr(10))
    str = Replace(str, "|", " ")
    manytoone = str

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Scott, so as for your first question, yet there can be multiple Line Breaks.
I've tried out your formula, and it works but only to an extent. It doesn't account for spaces preceeding the line breaks. I've edited my original question to clarify what I mean

Comment: My question was, is each line a single word?  If so we can remove a few steps and make it work.

Comment: @DannyMoncadea see edit, both will now deal with that.

Comment: @DannyMoncadea sorry forgot to hit enter on the edit.  Now both the code and the formula will deal with spaces on blank lines.

Comment: this works great! If you don't mind, could you explain to me the purpose of trimming? I don't understand why the text is trimmed, then has chr(10) converted to spaces in order to trim again. It seems as if trimming is essential to getting the correct output, but I don't understand why there needs to be all this conversion for it to work properly.

Comment: @DannyMoncadea `TRIM` will remove extra spaces, so any double, triple,... will become one space.  So we first trim the any extra spaces to one.  Then we replace all the char(10) and space-Char(10) with space and trim again to remove all the extra char(10).  Then move the remaining spaces to char(10).  But we also need to deal with the wanted spaces.  which we turn into "|" as place holders.

Comment: @DannyMoncadea please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular Expressions.

The regex pattern below removes any line that contains zero to any number of spaces, along with its terminating crlf, and also removes the crlf at the end of the final word.

```
Option Explicit
Sub trimXSLF()
    Dim myRng As Range, myCell As Range, WS As Worksheet
    Dim RE As Object
    Const sPat As String = "^\s*[\x0A\x0D]+|[\x0A\x0D](?!\s*\S+\s*)"
    Const sRepl As String = ""

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet4") 'or whatever
With WS
    Set myRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = sPat

    For Each myCell In myRng
        myCell = .Replace(myCell.Value2, sRepl)
    Next myCell

End With
End Sub
```

If `myRng` is large (tens of thousands of rows), the macro could run the process over a VBA array for speed.

Answer (score 0):

A VBA method would be replacing consecutive `vbLf` constants with a single one.

Loop through the string as long as there are more than one `vbLf` together, once removed, replace the string.

```
Sub RemoveExcessLinebreaks()

    Dim s As String, rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B4")
    s = rng.Value

    While InStr(1, s, vbLf & vbLf) > 0
        s = Replace(s, vbLf & vbLf, vbLf)
    Wend

    rng.Value = s

End Sub
```

Obviously, you would need to modify the `rng` object to your purposes, or turn it into a parameter to the sub itself.

`vbLf` is a constant for a "LineFeed". There are multiple types of new lines, such as a `vbCr` (Carriage Return) or a `vbCrLf` (combined). Pressing <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> in a cell appears to use the `vbLf` variant, which is why I used this constant over the others.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered fairly well, but not meeting one of the requirements yet (have 1 line between each new line), so here is my take on answering this. Please see the comments through the code for more details:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub reduceNewLines()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim lCol As Long: lCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Dim arrData As Variant: arrData = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lRow, lCol))
Dim arrVal() As String
Dim R As Long, C As Long, X As Long

For R = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData) 'Iterate through each row of data
    For C = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2) 'iterate through each column of data (though might be just 1)

        arrVal = Split(arrData(R, C), Chr(10)) 'allocate each row to an array, split at new line

        arrData(R, C) = "" 'reset the data inside this field

        For X = LBound(arrVal) To UBound(arrVal)
            arrVal(X) = Trim(arrVal(X)) 'clear leading/trailing spaces
            If Left(arrVal(X), 1) <> " " And arrVal(X) <> "" Then
                arrData(R, C) = arrData(R, C) & arrVal(X) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) 'allocate new data + 2 lines
            End If
        Next X

        arrData(R, C) = Left(arrData(R, C), Len(arrData(R, C)) - 2) 'remove the last 2 extra new lines
    Next C
Next R

ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lRow, lCol)) = arrData 'allocate the data back to the sheet

End Sub
```

Happy to assist further if needed.