# Inserting Chr(149) to delimit a paragraph?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell with multiple sections (some with more than 1 sentence) like this:

[image: Example of bulleted list from cell paragraph]

to form a paragraph. Every section starts with a proper case letter and ends with a period. Is there a way to loop through cells and bullet point `Chr(149)` the beginning of these sections? Is there a formula or VBA script that can loop through and add that character to the beginning of each section?

Comment: bullet is `char(149)`

Comment: Are each section on a new line in the cell already?

Comment: @ScottCraner every section is within the cell.

Comment: Yes but if you wrap the text in the cell are they on their own line in that cell?

Comment: Consider putting this kind of formatted text inside a shape (could be transparent) rather than a cell - especially if there are (or could be) more than 255 characters in the cell.

Comment: @ScottCraner I figured out a way to separate into columns by doing text to columns and then in the delimted other space putting `ctrl+J`. Now I just need to loop through each column and have every cell start with `Chr(149)`

Comment: @ScottCraner which I can do with this: `=CHAR(149)&" "&G2`

Comment: If that is the case then if you still want it in one cell, with your data before the text to column in A1: `=CHAR(149) & " " & SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10), CHAR(10) & CHAR(149) & " ")`

Comment: @ScottCraner you are unbelievable........ Can you put that as an answer so I can give you credit? Thank you so much, Scott!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your data in A1:

```
=CHAR(149) & " " & SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10), CHAR(10) & CHAR(149) & " ")
```

[image]

Comment: I have instances where there are empty cells that just have `Chr(149)` and a space, how can I replace all those to be blank? I can't type in `Chr(149) *` in the replace what part because that will also target areas where text comes after the space

Comment: I just need a way to delete a bullet point that doesn't have any text after the space

Comment: @nicklanta see here to get rid of extra line breaks first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402311/reducing-number-of-line-breaks-chr10-in-a-cell